# Custom View Label Won't Change

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

My view contain a button which bring a custom view which contain a `ContainerView` and it has a label. When I bring the custom view to the front I get the label text empty. So please where would be my issue?

View Controller Code:

```
@IBAction func PushAlert(sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("alertViewController") as! AlertViewController

    var alertText = AlertTextViewController()

    alertText.lblText = "DONE"

    alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    alert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

---

```
class AlertTextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblAlertText: UILabel!
    var lblText = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblAlertText.text = lblText
    }
}
```

I have created a link for the source code which will be much easier to understand [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kgek7t2wfx78lz/TestView.zip?dl=0)

Comment: In the source you've put in here, where exactly is the label supposed to be shown that is empty?

Comment: It is supposed to be shown under the "Alert View" text as in the storyboard @BrandonShega

Comment: The `AlertTextViewController` you are setting the label text on isn't the same as the one that is contained in your `AlertViewController`, it's a new instance that you are creating and that gets destroyed at the end of the method.  You need to add a method to `AlertViewController` that you can pass text to and have that method find the embedded `AlertTextViewController` and set the label text on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about var `lblText: String?` in your `AlertTextViewController`.

Maybe it's overriden by your declaration (for some reason I wouldn't be able to explain)?

Or wait, I'm confused by

`var alertText = AlertTextViewController()`

as you are presenting creating and presenting the ViewController `alert`. How is `alertText` and `alert` related?

Edit:

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var alertText: AlertTextViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! AlertTextViewController
    alertText.lblAlertText.text = "Test"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Do this in your AlertViewController, and it works. I don't know what your final purpose is though, and this might not be the most elegant solution. I've created an outlet, the containerView to your class.

Comment: Both are in the same view so shouldn't AlertTextViewController get called before I present AlertViewController?

Comment: Sorry, I confused some variable names, I will take a look at the source code provided.

Comment: I think the issue is AlertTextViewController is called before AlertViewController so it won't show the text. I couldn't know how to solve it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused by container views and embedded segues, since I haven't used it, but I really can't understand the connection between your alert and your alertText. How would `alert` understand it's going to use the embedded segue to present the `alertText` controller you created?

Comment: I wish I can know that which will solve my problem :(

Comment: My updated version solves it, but I don't know what your final intentions are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83770/discussion-between-luai-kalkatawi-and-mattias).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a order of events problem. Try setting lblAlertText.text in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad.